# Foundation6 bottom off-canvas resize CSS

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I want to change my bottom off-canvas height, but I'm using only css and not sass. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

based on the docs I think this will do the work:

In your custom apps.css:

```
.off-canvas.position-bottom{
    height: 150px;
    transform: translateY(150px);
    }
```

Edit:

This is the exact example on what I tested before posting... once again... at me is working... the example is hazadous, but its not long and it's easy to understand, I let only the off-canvas bottom

```
<html>
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foundation.min.css">

<style type="text/css">

    .fill{
        height: 400px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: red;
        display: block;
    }
    .off-canvas-wrapper{
        height: 1500px;
        width: 400px;
    }

    .position-bottom{
        height: 50px;
    }

</style>
```

```
<div class="off-canvas-wrapper">

    <div class="off-canvas position-bottom" id="offCanvasBottom1" data-off-canvas>
        <div class='fill'></div>
    </div>

    <div class="off-canvas-content" data-off-canvas-content>
        <button type="button" class="button" data-toggle="offCanvasLeft1">Open Left</button>
        <button type="button" class="button" data-toggle="offCanvasRight1">Open Right</button>
        <button type="button" class="button" data-toggle="offCanvasTop1">Open Top</button>
        <button type="button" class="button" data-toggle="offCanvasBottom1">Open Bottom</button>
    </div>

</div>

<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: This not working for me. I tried on latest Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu 16.04 On chrome nothing has changed, on Firefox I can't see even the little off-canvas.

Comment: You did a mistake I think... It should be worked flawless

Comment: I edited my answer... also, check the official page, with inspector,... there you can see that javascript add's on the offset a class: "is-open" that only overwrite the transform method.

Comment: This still not working for me. Even this example, either.

Comment: try this: .position-bottom{
        height: 50px !important;
    }    and also do you try to modify with inspector, what does inspector say?